# GraphQL: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql

I was trying to run below sql code in grahpql. but I got `"missing FROM-clause entry for table \"usefulLinks\""`. How can I solve this issue?

```
  const subUsefulLinkQuery = queryBuilder('usefulLinks').select('*').rowNumber('row_num', {
    column: 'index',
    order: 'asc',
  });

  const subWhereQuery = queryBuilder('usefulLinks')
    .with('with_order_number', subUsefulLinkQuery)
    .select('row_num')
    .from('with_order_number')
    .where('id', '=', after);
    
  query = query
    .with('with_order_number', subUsefulLinkQuery)
    .from('with_order_number')
    .where('row_num', '>', subWhereQuery);
```

[image]